# CSS Horizontal Nav with image swap not working

Tags: html, css, navigation, horizontallist

Can't figure out what I did wrong...

http://tacticaloffense.com/indexNew.php

Here is my HTML:

```
  <div id="headerTopNav">
    <ul id="topNav">
      <li id="home"><a href="index.php" class="home">Home</a></li>
      <li id="about"><a href="about.php" class="about">About</a></li>
      <li id="products"><a href="shop/index.php" class="products">Products</a></li>
      <li id="wpNews"><a href="news/index.php" class="wpNews">News</a></li>
      <li id="contact"><a href="contact.php" class="contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
#headerTopNav {
    position:absolute;
    top:11px;
    left:520px;
    height:30px;
}
#topNav {
    height:30px;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    display:inline;
}
#topNav li {
    list-style:none;
    display:inline;
}
#topNav li:after {
    border-right:1px solid #063d04;
}
#topNav li:last-child {
    border:none;
}
#topNav a {
    background:url(../img/nav/nav_map.png);
    display:inline-block;
    height:30px;
    text-indent:-9000px;
}
#topNav a.home,
#topNav a.about,
#topNav a.products,
#topNav a.wpNews,
#topNav a.contact {
    height:30px;
}
#topNav li#home, #topNav a.home {
    width:77px;
}
#topNav li#about, #topNav a.about {
    width:102px;
}
#topNav li#products, #topNav a.products {
    width:99px;
}
#topNav li#wpNews, #topNav a.wpNews {
    width:72px;
}
#topNav li#contact, #topNav a.contact {
    width:92px;
}

#topNav a.home:link, #topNav a.home:visited {
    background:url(../img/nav/nav_map.png) no-repeat -246px 0px;
}
#topNav a.home:hover {
    background:url(../img/nav/nav_map.png) no-repeat -246px -30px;
}
#topNav a.about:link, #topNav a.about:visited {
    background:url(../img/nav/nav_map.png) no-repeat 0px 0px;
}
#topNav a.about:hover {
    background:url(../img/nav/nav_map.png) no-repeat 0px -30px;
}
#topNav a.products:link, #topNav a.products:visited {
    background:url(../img/nav/nav_map.png) no-repeat -570px 0px;
}
#topNav a.products:hover {
    background:url(../img/nav/nav_map.png) no-repeat -570px -30px;
}
#topNav a.wpNews:link, #topNav a.wpNews:visited {
    background:url(../img/nav/nav_map.png) no-repeat -447px -60px;
}
#topNav a.wpNews:hover {
    background:url(../img/nav/nav_map.png) no-repeat -447px -90px;
}
#topNav a.contact:link, #topNav a.contact:visited {
    background:url(../img/nav/nav_map.png) no-repeat -140px -60px;
}
#topNav a.contact:hover {
    background:url(../img/nav/nav_map.png) no-repeat -140px -90px;
}
```

Can anyone help with this?  I am trying to do a horizontal navigation menu with images so that you see an image per link, and a different one when you hover over each one.  10 images in all.

Comment: So what is the problem?  How about putting together a fiddle or link to test page so those answering the question don't have to do this themselves?

Comment: Can you link us to a page so we can work with your images?

Comment: What is the purpose of the empty list items with .spacer? You have no css or js to explain their purpose.

Comment: I forgot to put in the spacer code. It is up there now, but not showing up on the page. Also, I have added a link to the page at the top of my original post.  I have also updated the CSS above from the below mentioned resolution which was unsuccessful.

Comment: The spacer class is redundant and makes for a sloppy mark-up. If you want a separator you can use `border` or `border-image` on the `li`, or add it as a pseudo-element by using `li:after`

Comment: If I do an `li:after` then it will show up after the last one which obviously I dont want. I prefer to leave it as is, just working as it should be for the way I have it. Border, same thing, it will show up on the last one which I don't want.

Comment: So you override it with the pseudo-selector `li:last-child {border:none;}` or attach a `.last` class to the last li and set `.last {border:none;}`

Comment: I have edited the HTML and the CSS as you suggested with the border property and made the corrections above.  No border, still have a gap, still no rollover effect, and the links do not work.  Any more ideas?  Thanks for your help by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's your `#logo` that covers the menu. Either apply a width to the logo or `z-index` to the menu. One of the below solves your problem.

Either this

```
#logo {
  padding-left: 45px;
  padding-top: 21px;
  position: relative;
  width: 360px;
}
```

Or this

```
#topNav {
  display: inline;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that was it! I have been beating my head on my desk for a day and a half now for something as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

put the inline in the ul class.
you also should apply a width to the li elements.

Comment: Adding the width the li elements helped, but there is still no hover effect and I dont have any spacer.

Comment: for spacing add margin-left: 5px; to the li.

Comment: for hover, just try adding a background-color and see if that works, then you will know if its your code or image error.